# How can I upload a code animated graphic that I made using java to Wordpress?

Tags: java, wordpress, parallax, interactive

I created a graphic that I animated using html, css3, java and some other java script plugin. I want to be able to upload that graphic to my WordPress site and show it in my portfolio page . The graphic is interactive meaning that when you tilt o your device it moves. Is there a way i can upload or my code files and make it work?